# Ideal Folder Structure of MVC framework

Tags: php, directory-structure

I would like to ask what is the ideal folder structure for a MVC framework that should be able to support multiple installations. For example, I install xyz framework and i run two or more sites based on this single installation of xyz framework rather than installing the framework for each site.

This is probably done in Codeigniter too but i don't know much about CodeIgniter, so i need your suggestions. I know some of you might even have better idea than what is done by CodeIgniter, so please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, a generalized example, of my MVC library structure. Nothing fancy, i wanted to keep it simple.

```
Library
    - Configuration
    - Modules (Database adapters etc)
    - Core (Abstract controllers, routing functionality etc)
Application
    - Model
    - View
    - Controllers
    - Helpers
```

The benefits with this structure is that the library is not (which it shouldnt) dependent of the library. That means that you can copy the library for use with other projects.

Comment: To add on, that would mean each app gets its own folder:

    Library
    App1
    App2
    ...

but calls the same Library (CakePHP, CI, etc.) This way apps & core files are decoupled

Comment: How any sane programmer could make it the other way, where framework and application files are mixed, is beyond me :p

Comment: I'd definitely put the config folder in the application folder, and rename the 'library' folder to something else.