# What folder structure do you use

Tags: php

Whether you structure your PHP application yourself or use a framework (MVC or other), what folder structure do you find most logical and you've been finding that you've been sticking to.

I still haven't developed a folder structure that I'm committed to, but I noticed that all my projects even the 2 page ones at least have a `webroot` folder (for files like htaccess, index, css, havascript) and another folder for the above the web root stuff where I try to keep as much of the files as possible. Pretty basic. Hoping to hear what others are doing to keep their programs organized.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795136/ideal-folder-structure-of-mvc-framework and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040308/folder-structure-of-a-php-mvc-framework-am-i-doing-this-right/

Comment: @Serge, thanks for the useful links. But I'm not biased towards the MVC architecture in particular. Any folder structure is fine including the 1 file per page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Default Folder Structure for web projects is

```
+projectname/
  +htdocs/
  | +assets/
  | | +js/
  | | +css/
  | | +img/
  | | +swf/
  | +content/
  +sys/
  | +temp/
  | +config/
  | +libs/
  +docs
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use a framework, I would recommend sticking to the folder structure recommended for the framework. This means once you learn it, you can more easily adapt to other projects made using the said framework, and other coders familiar with the framework will understand yours easier as well.

Answer (score 3):

For **minor projects** I usually use the following to work from:

- `httpdocs` (web root)

  - `data-providers` (AJAX endpoints)
  - `script` (JS: utilities, scripts, libraries)
  - `style` (CSS and graphics - mainly [sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) instead of the `gfx` folder I used to have)
- `models` (PHP classes)

As for the PHP files in `httpdocs` I usually use one file per page / functionality (including basic [CRUD operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)).

Comment: So you put PHP files for CRUD operations in httpdocs, along with PHP files for web pages? What kind of files are in "data-providers" then? And how do you access the models? using "../" path?

Comment: @Tomas Models are `__autoload`'ed from a `.htaccess` included config.php file residing in the parent folder of `httpdocs` and `models`. `data-providers` contains resources to return fragments, e.g., city-for-zip etc. loaded via jQuery. As for the CRUD operations: a file - e.g., `user.php` - will (per default) show a `User` instance but handles creation and update as well. Not really MVC, I know, but these are minor (mostly private) projects.

Answer (score 2):

I generally follow something similar to Martin Holzhauer, however I keep any common php includes in a separate tree (referenced via the include_path - call it common libs).

Each page intended to be addressable directly via the browser is created as index.php in its own directory. include files (or any additional content) specific to only that single page go in that directory, common includes go into the common libs.

By keeping the upload temp and include content outside the web root it simplifies security somewhat.

In practice I actually have several include paths - for a full explanation see article in PHP Architect earlier this year - but this allows me to control different setups (e.g. database settings) for dev / staging / live. And also to override particular files (e.g. to add additional logging / diagnostics)