# where to put the server side php file?

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax

I'm using simple apache http linux mandriva server. I have created an ajax page to store some data on MySQL database in server. I have also written one server side php file. I'm confused actually where should I put my server side php file (e.g. in root or ..)?

Thanks.

Comment: you can follow MVC folder structre. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795136/ideal-folder-structure-of-mvc-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call it directly with AJAX, then it will need to be web accessible. Exactly where you put it in your site structure is up to you.

I'd suggest a sub directory - res, services, etc - to keep things organized if you have several of these files.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own MVC :)

http://www.phpied.com/ajax-mvc/